# How do I copy a big database table to another in ABAP?

Tags: database, abap, sap-ase

I want to copy one big database table to another. This is my current approach:

```
OPEN CURSOR WITH HOLD lv_db_cursor FOR
  SELECT * FROM zcustomers.

DO.
  REFRESH gt_custom.
  FETCH NEXT CURSOR lv_db_cursor
    INTO TABLE  gt_custom
    PACKAGE SIZE lv_package_size.

  IF sy-subrc NE 0.
    CLOSE CURSOR lv_db_cursor.
    EXIT.
  ENDIF.

  INSERT zcustomers1 FROM TABLE gt_custom.

  * Write code to modify u r custom table from gt_custom .
ENDDO.
```

But the problem is that I get a error "Enterprise]ASE has run out of LOCKS".
I tried to use `COMMIT` statement after insert some piece of records, but it closes the cursor.
I don't want to increase max locks by database setting or make a copy on database level.
I want to understand how I can copy with best performance and low usage memory in ABAP...
Thank you.

Comment: But "copy on database level" would be the best thing to do in this case?

Comment: Yes. I agree. But I learn performance  protentional problem.

Comment: This is not an ABAP issue, it is an ASE issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [`COMMIT CONNECTION`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapcommit_rollback_connection.htm?file=abapcommit_rollback_connection.htm) instead of [`COMMIT WORK`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapcommit.htm?file=abapcommit.htm) it is possible to commit only the transaction writing to zcustomers1, while keeping the transaction reading from zcustomers open.

Note that having multiple transactions (one reading, multiple writing) can create inconsistencies in the database if zcustomers or zcustomers1 are written while this code runs. Also reading from zcustomers1 shows only a part of the entries from zcustomers.

```
DATA:
  gt_custom       TYPE TABLE OF ZCUSTOMERS,
  lv_package_size TYPE i,
  lv_db_cursor    TYPE cursor.

lv_package_size = 10000.

OPEN CURSOR WITH HOLD lv_db_cursor FOR
  SELECT * FROM zcustomers.

DO.
  REFRESH gt_custom.

  FETCH NEXT CURSOR lv_db_cursor
    INTO TABLE   gt_custom
    PACKAGE SIZE lv_package_size.

  IF sy-subrc NE 0.
    CLOSE CURSOR lv_db_cursor.
    EXIT.
  ENDIF.

  MODIFY zcustomers2 FROM TABLE gt_custom.
  " regularily commiting here releases a partial state to the database
  " through that, locks are released and running into ASE error SQL1204 is avoided
  COMMIT CONNECTION default.
ENDDO.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also "copy on database level" from within ABAP SQL using a [combined `INSERT` and `SELECT`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapinsert_source.htm#!ABAP_ALTERNATIVE_3@3@):

```
INSERT zcustomers1 FROM ( SELECT * FROM zcustomers ).
```

Unlike the other solution, this runs in one single transaction (no inconsistency on the database) and avoids moving the data between the database and the ABAP server, so should be by magnitudes faster. However, like the code in question this might still run into database limits due to opening many locks during the insert (though might avoid other problems). This should be solved [on database side](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0002635483) and is not a  limitation of ABAP.

Comment: Yes. I try this. But i learn performance protentional problem. I need to get any way where possible make  this task correctly.  Is it possible to make it by Abap. For example use cursor with commit little piece of rows to avoid growing locks on database.

Comment: The same problem.  Is it possible to make this without increasing number of database locks objects?  Database error text: "SQL message: [ASE Error SQL1204][SAP][ASE ODBC
  Driver][Adaptive Server Enterprise]ASE has run out of LOCKS.   Thank you!

Comment: But "increasing number of database objects" is exactly [what you need to do](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0002635483) if you need a bulk import in a single transaction. If you want to do this in multiple transactions, you need to share more details on the table (how many entries, primary keys, is data inserted at the same time??)

Comment: I want to do with multiple transaction. Structure is  flat table ID as char12, First Name, Second Name fields,   ID is a primary key, in numeric format but field is char12.

Comment: @Stas is the ID an increasing sequence? Or a UUID? Are entries inserted into zcustomers while this migration is running?

Comment: Yes.  ID is increase sequence like 000000001234, 000000001235....   char12 type.

Comment: If i can use select with range, i can be complete this task.   But it does not work , when I cast in select ID field, con not use  IDS in WHERE clause.                                     SELECT FROM ZCUSTOMERS
           FIELDS CAST( ID AS INT8 ) as IDS
          WHERE IDS > low and IDS < high INTO...............